# Command not found despite pip installing in dockerfile

Tags: python, database, docker, shell, sudo

I am new to Docker and am struggling with an issue.

I am running a makefile which runs a docker-compose. I am getting `poetry not found` when building my docker image despite pip installing it before.

```
FROM python:3.9

# Getting sudo
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get -y install sudo

# Adding group to sudo
RUN useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && adduser docker sudo
USER docker

# Installing poetry
ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.1.14
RUN pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"

WORKDIR /jimmy

COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml /jimmy/
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false 
RUN poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-ansi

# Mounting network data to a new dir to get data and models
RUN mkdir dvc_mount \
&& sudo mount -t nfs placeholder_ip:dvc dvc_mount \
&& dvc remote add -d mounted_directory dvc_mount \
&& dvc pull

COPY . /jimmy
EXPOSE 8080
ENV PYTHONPATH=/jimmy

CMD [ "python", "jimmy/jimmy_api.py", "--conf", "config.json" ]
```

It was working fine before I added a new user group which gets sudo permissions. I tried removing this but this will yield a permission denied problem when running `sudo mount`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are creating a new user called "docker" with sudo permissions, and then you switch to that user using the USER directive but sudo command is not available in the image because not included in python:3.9 base image

Comment: You can't usually `mount` anything in a container in any case, and if you could `RUN mount` it wouldn't be persisted in the final image (or even in the next `RUN` command).  Can you remove all of the `dvc` related calls (and the unnecessary `sudo` installation and ineffective `docker` group)?

Comment: Thank you for the information. I indeed removed all these related calls and instead orchestrated the mount via the docker-compose.yml file. This solved my problems somewhat. Thank you.